# Determine suitable quadraples of positive integers satisying the following conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers

I need some advice on how to proceed on with this question:

Determine all possible quadruples of positive integers $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that

$a^3=b^2$ ,  $c^3=d^2$   and $c-a=7$.

So far I have gathered the following:

$c^3-a^3=d^2-b^2$ and so $(c-a)(c^2+ac+a^2)=(d-b)(d+b)$

$7((c-a)^2+3ac)=(d-b)(d+b)$

$7(49+3a(a+7)=(d-b)(d+b)$

$7(3a^2+21a+49)=(d-b)(d+b)$

and I'm stuck here. However I do realised that $(3a^2+21a+49)$ is unfactorizable. So does it imply that $(3a^2+21a+49)$ is prime too?

If so I can conclude that (d-b)(d+b) is a product of 7 and a prime number. To which, either

$(d-b)=7, (d+b) = $ a prime number OR  $d-b= $ a prime number, $d+b=7$

Would greatly appreciated if someone can enlighten me on this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: there is no known formula to generate primes only, so no.

Now, since $a^3=b^2$ and $c^3=d^2,$ the Unique factorization Theorem implies that the exponent of any prime factor of $a$ must be even and the same happens with $c$ and so $c-a$ is a difference of squares and hence...

Comment: Hi may I ask why must the exponent of any prime factor of a be even?

Comment: Let $p$ be any prime and let $e_p(k)$ be the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $k=a,b$ (if $p\nmid k$ then $e_p(k)=0$). Then $3e_p(a)=2e_p(b)$ and since $\gcd(2,3)=1$ then $2$ must divide $e_p(a).$ The same argument works with $c.$